# Choosing a value corresponding the the greatest index in an Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table

| index | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pear | a |
| 2 | apple | a |
| 1 | peach | b |

I would like to group by one column (type) and show the value corresponding to the largest index. How can I best do that?

The long way around would be

```
with foo as (
  select t1.type, max(t1.index) max_index
  from tab t1
)
select foo.type, t2.value
from foo
left join tab t2 on t2.type = foo.type and t2.index = foo.max_index
```

but is there a better way? Better being, in this case, more readable/maintainable, performant, and shorter (in roughly that order).